# Write single information to database

Tags: java, android, database, jdbc

I have a table "table1" in my database. This table have a column "column1" set to "double"

Now i trying to save this value "10.9999999" to my "column1" like this

```
 try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user1, pass1);

            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "INSERT INTO column1 " +
                    "VALUES (10.9999999)";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);



        }catch(SQLException se){

            se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{

            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
            }
            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And column1 is still empty, what is wrong here ?

Comment: What exceptions do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Take note that it's `table_name` and NOT `column_name`! You need to put the name of your table there.

Comment: String sql = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (10.9999999)"; still column1 is empty